# Get fields from multiple sub-documents that match a condition in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

below is my collection in mongodb -

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50f69176904e1d66affec20d"),
    "connections" : [
    {
        "id" : "50f651a3b58bba7fbec2f222"
    },
    {
        "group" : "Roomies",
        "users" : [
        {
            "id" : "50f651a3b58bba7fbec2f222"
        },
        {
            "id" : "50f651b8b58bba7fbec2f223"
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "group" : "College",
        "users" : [
        {
            "id" : "50f651b8b58bba7fbec2f223"
        },
        {
            "id" : "50f651a3b58bba7fbec2f222"
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "group" : "Work",
        "users" : [
        {
            "id" : "50f651a3b58bba7fbec2f222"
        }
        ]
    },
],
"email" : "arunko350@gmail.com",
"name" : "Arun"
}
```

Here i want to get all the group names in which id = 50f651a3b58bba7fbec2f222 exists. Please help me. I am browsing for 2 days for the solution.

Comment: It would help if you fixed the indenting of the docs in your question.

Comment: hey @JohnnyHK. i have indented the code. Please check it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with MongoDB 2.2's [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/).  In the shell:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
      // Duplicate the docs, one per connections array element.
      {$unwind: '$connections'},
      // Only include the docs with the specified user id
      {$match: {'connections.users.id': '50f651a3b58bba7fbec2f222'}},
      // Bring group out to the only top level field and exclude _id
      {$project: {_id: 0, group: '$connections.group'}}
])
```

outputs:

```js
{
  "result": [
    {
      "group": "Roomies"
    },
    {
      "group": "College"
    },
    {
      "group": "Work"
    }
  ],
  "ok": 1
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you Johnny. It works :). Do you have any idea about lithium framework? I had the difficulty to convert this command to lithium specific command.

Comment: @Arunko.  Cool.  Sorry, I haven't used the Lithium framework.

Answer (score -1):

$elemMatch operator can be used for projection on array elements.

> http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/#_S_elemMatch

The following should be ok

```
var projection = {"connections.group":1, "connections":{$elemMatch: {"users.id":"507c35dd8fada716c89d0013"}}}

db.collection.find( {{"connections.users.id": "507c35dd8fada716c89d0013"}}, projection);
```

Comment: i get this error :
> db.users.find( {"connections.users.id": "50f651b8b58bba7fbec2f223"}, {"connections.group" : 1, "connections.users" : {$elemMatch : {"id" : "50f651b8b58bba7fbec2f223"}}});


error: {
 "$err" : "Cannot use $elemMatch projection on a nested field (currently unsupported).",
 "code" : 16344
}

Comment: I updated the projection to make it usable. But this will also return only one element from the array as elemMatch operator chooses only one element from the array. Sorry bro http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/#_S_elemMatch

Comment: Seems like there is an open ticket for this issue: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831. For now you can retrieve the documents that matches your query and extract group names manually by iterating over the documents. good luck

Comment: hey man. do you know about lithium framework? I got the query. if you could convert it to lithium syntax then it would be helpful.

Comment: No I don't know lithium syntax.

Comment: have you tested this? The second projection will overwrite the first so ''connections.group" will be excluded. The second projection is invalid so it will also default to 0. In your example, the only thing that will show up is the default _id